# Importing android-crop library in my project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my app I want to implement **android-crop** library: https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

I'm using eclipse. I have installed gradle plugin , but I'm new in gradle and I don't now how to import this library in my project and use it. When I import this library I get project like on image, but I can't launch this example application.

[image: library downlaoded as zip file and imported in eclipse]

Can some one tell me how to import library in my project and how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Very easy to do in Android Studio.  I know that's not your question but I'm just sayin'

Comment: I just install Android Studio. I must import all my projects to android studio :)

Comment: It is pretty easy to do.  I created a new Android Studio project and then I just imported each of the Eclipse projects into it using the "File -> Import Module" function which worked like a charm.  I did not use the Eclipse export feature.  AS will automatically create the "build.gradle" file and move the "src" and "res" directories into the right place in AS.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Eclipse** you should:

- clone the repo locally
- import the code in your workspace starting from lib folder. The Wizard will import the code in lib/src/main. I suggest you naming it "croplib" (or another name) instead of "main".
- mark java(*) folder as source (click on folder -> Build-Path -> use as source folder).
- mark croplib as Android Library (Properties -> Android -> Is library)
- Clean and build

I suggest you switching to **Android Studio**.
In this case, just open your project and add this dependency to your build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:0.9.10@aar'
```